# Bootstrap doesn't work in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form made, but it doesn't appear correctly in Firefox... All other browsers seem to work. I've tried everything!

Here's the link: http://www.redmandesign.ie/bootstrap/form1.html

I think it's related to the bootstrap style sheet but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help, I'm really stuck!!!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What firefox version is causing an issue for you? What is the issue? What is not displaying correctly? We need more info.

Answer (score 12):

```
<link href="css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css\bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Should be changed to:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Explanation: Firefox is sending a request for a file called css\bootstrap.css instead of asking for bootstrap.css in the css folder, which doesn't exist and the server replies with a 404 error.  Don't you just love the subtle difference between the types of slashes? :P

Comment: Good going... it's curious that most browsers correct for the mistake. Go figure.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, this will completely break some angular apps. Bower builds for js files will throw in alternating \ in srcript src tags and this will cause you days of suffering.

Answer (score 2):

In firefox , when you check for this link  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css. It shows this connection is untrusted. Accept it and Procced it from the browser. Now run the bootstrap file, it should work.